# Testing threaded code in Django

Tags: django, multithreading, unit-testing, testing, sqlite

I'm testing the Django views - a view, that contains a class in itself. Can anyone help me to solve this problem: how I can to mock class or another way to test this view, because without mocking I get the error: `OperationalError: no such table:` - as I understand the test database is empty in new thread(I use sqlite3 in-memory for testing), but I don't know how to solve this problem.

View:

```
def view(self):
    import threading

    class Fun(threading.Thread):
        def run(self):
            SomeModel.class_method() - this method remove and create SomeModel instances
    Fun().start()
    return render_to_response('some_html.html')
```

Comment: I advise against starting threads in views to perform background tasks. Use a queue like celery or rq instead.

Comment: This is a good advice. Thanks a lot, Daniel.